# how to style an input [type=image] button, and add a text value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my button:

```
<input name="Submit" type="image" src="some_button.jpg"/>
```

I would like to remove the src, give it a text value, and style with css, like this:

```
<input name="Submit" type="image" value="Next" class="mybutton"/>
```

The problem is that the value appears in Chrome and Safari with an ugly gray border around it.  My research tells me that an input `type=image` must always have a src, but when I give it an invisible 1x1.png, the border goes away, but so does the text value.

I realize I can easily resolve this by changing to `type="submit"`, but I am retrofitting a design to a pre-existing program, and must keep `type="image"` in order to preserve the script.

What are my options??

********Edit:************

Please see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p486cprm/
Look for the ugly gray border.  Not the same as the input border.

Comment: Could you not simply hide this input and replace it with the text input when appropriate? or have i misunderstood the issue?

Comment: I need this input as it triggers the submit function for the form.  The script is triggered by an input of type "image".  (Not my doing!  But these are the cards I have to work with...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code for your button image and give it text-indent to omit button value.

```
 .buttonname {
    background: url(some_button.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 150px; /*as per your wish*/
    height: 150px; /*as per your wish*/
    border: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this help?  Can you add it to my fiddle?  https://jsfiddle.net/p486cprm/

Comment: @p1xelarchitect Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/p486cprm/1/

Comment: yes, that removes the gray border, but it would break my script.  My one requirement is to keep type="image".  Unfortunately...

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn{
width:100px;
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<input class="btn" type="image" name="submit" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/f/d/n/5/p/g/button-red-next.svg">
```

please go through this code

Comment: no, this does not work because i want to control the style via css, and i want the value to be text based, not image based.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it:

```
<label for="Submit" class="mybutton">
    Next
    <input name="Submit" id="Submit" type="image" src="blank.png"/>
</label>
```